# How to remove duplicate users from a list but amalgamate their roles

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a list of People who have a name and a list of roles:

Each item in the list is of type PersonDetails:

```
public class PersonDetails
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So in my list of these items I might have the following:

1. Id 23 Eric whose roles contains a role with Role.Name = "Manager"
2. Id 23 Eric whose roles contains a role with Role.Name = "CEO"
3. Id 23 Eric whose roles contains a role with Role.Name = "CIO"

so that is how it is currently but because it is the same person I want my list to be:

1. Id 23 Eric whose roles contains "Manager", "CEO", "CIO"

Can anyone tell me how to change my list of items to be like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from details in detailsList
group details by new {Id = details.Id, Name = details.Name} into groupedDetails
select new PersonDetails()
{
    Id = groupedDetails.Key.Id,
    Name = groupingDetails.Key.Name,
    Roles = groupingDetails.SelectMany(member => member.Roles).ToList()
}
```

I havent tested this yet, but I think it will work.